# Link list items to the calendar and create events

Tags: 2013, list, sharepoint-calendar, list-form

we're using SharePoint 2013 at the office, I am a backend developer in c# and know very little about SharePoint. I was tasked with building a form in SharePoint to capture data and then create a calendar event with that data. Like I said I have very little to no experience with SharePoint so any guidelines as to what SharePoint Apps I must use will be appreciated! detailed spec below:

It's basically an internal sales system of dead assets. Each asset uploaded must have the following properties:

- Name
- Asset number
- [Pictures] (upload)
- [documentation] (upload)
- comment
- Expiry Date (Links to the calendar and must display on home page calendar)

Only some users must be able to add new items to the list so I'm thinking some sort of data capture form with limited accessibility

All users must be able to go through a list of all assets and view pictures, documentation, etc...

The most important thing is the items (assets) showing on the calendar on the SharePoint home page

I don't expect anyone to do my job for me, I just need to be pointed in the right direction. Thank you all!

[image: calendar on home page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing if the item is one per entry is to add the columns you have listed to the calendar entry.

Create one calendar and in the settings add the columns
Name
Asset number
[Pictures] (upload) (you can attach file to the calendar entry)
[documentation] (upload) (you can attach file to the calendar entry)
comment

Your expiry date will be the item of the calendar (click on make this an all day event)

List security of the calendar can be set via the permission structure of the library

This is the easiest, fastest and most brutal way to achieve your goal, despite not being the fanciest and an intermediate level sharepoint person can do this in 30-40 minutes. An expert can do it in 5 minutes.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I created a new calendar as defined above and it works really well, my only issue now is we have two different calendars, is there any way I can show those events in the main calendar on the home page? see screenshot in main post

Comment: Thank you, this worked quite well.

Comment: I am not familiar with the calendar in the picture and it does not look like a native sharepoint thing, is it an app purchased from the store? or a completely coded one?